# Mass configure ILO?

Tags: windows, hp, hp-proliant, ilo

Is it possible to mass change ILO settings with HP Systems Insight Manager?

I am looking for an automated method of getting all my organizations servers power settings configured the same Ilo. Basically I want all my servers enabled for "Automatically Power On Server" and "Power delay to 30 seconds"

How do I go about this? I have looked all over the interface but am not seeing an obvious method of achieving this.

So far I have created a group but cant see a a way of changing the power settings and mass deploy it.

Systems Insight Manager 7.0.0 - Windows
80+ Hp Proliant G4, G5, G6 and G7 Servers.

Comment: Curious. Why delay 30 seconds? Would the `random` setting be more appropriate? What issue are you looking to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prepare a XML file containing the settings and use a script that pushes it out to all nodes you want to update.

An example of how to do this can be found [here](http://practicaladmin.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/ilo-bulk-update-script)

On how to prepare the XML (RIBCL) file, see the [HP Lights Out Scripting Guide](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DocumentIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&contentType=SupportManual&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=4154735)

Answer (score 2):

This could either be a case for ILO scripting using the [`hponcfg` online configuration utility](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user:13325%20hponcfg) *or* possibly [conrep](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14224_na/14224_na.html) (to mass-apply BIOS settings). The problem I see is that the ILO and server power capabilities are different between the G4 and G7 systems, for example...

So you may have to do this in batches of like-generation servers.